# To backup sharepoint, do I just have to backup the SQL database?

Tags: sql-server, backup, sharepoint

Sharepoint is basically running SQL Server under the hood as I understand it.

Is backing up sharepoint as simple as just backing up the underlying SQL Server databases?

Or do I also need some files from the filesystem in the backup?

Comment: Not sure, but to find out: try it, and do a restore. If you can restore it, you're good. If you can't, keep working until you can. A backup _doesn't exist_ until you've restored from it at least once. Testing and _documenting_ the restore process should always be part of setting up your backups.

Comment: I'm not a Sharepoint expert, but my understanding was "if you have the database you can get Sharepoint back even if all else is gone, but it won't be pretty".  That said, I would presume that using Sharepoint Central Admin's backup utilities would be the better approach as well as following MS best practices or using a 3rd party utility that has API hooks that back it up correctly.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not just SQL. Microsoft has implementation guides for each version of SharePoint; read them, particularly the sections on backing up and restoring. There are SP-specific tools to do this, and most commercial backup software will have a module for SP, just like they have modules for SQL and Exchange.

That said, I think The Cleaner is right, that you *can* manage a restore if SQL is all you have. Doesn't mean that's a good way to go about it. And also Joel's point is fantastic. No one cares about backups, they're a necessary evil to enable you to do restores.